# $_SESSION showing defined and undefined when checked from an input form

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is show a two seperate divs in the same spot depending on if the $_SESSION is set. The form shows when no $_SESSION is noticed and the account info shows when there is a $_SESSION. whats happening is when I sign in and it all goes through it sends me to the same screen with the same form but when I refresh the browser the account info shows up replacing the form. Can anyone see why the exchange isn't going on when I initially sign someone in and the $_SESSION is set?

```
$signedIn='<h3 id="signedInHeader">Welcome </h3><p><a href="convenientaddaddress.php"> Add Address </a></p>
<p><a href="convenientaccountinfo.php"> Account Info </a></p>
<p><a href="convenientsignout.php"> Sign Out </a></p>
<p><a href="convenientaddcreditcard.php"> Add C Card </a></p>';


    $form='<form id="signInForm" method="POST" action="index.php"><h3 id="formHeader">Sign Into Account</h3><br/>
    <p id="pRegister"><a id="register" href="convenientregisterpage.php"> Register </a></p><br/>
    <label>Email Addr:</label><input type="text" name="userEmail" id="email" size="15"/><br/>
    <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="formSubmit" name="submit"/> </form>';
$username='';
$username=$_SESSION['userName'];
if(!$username){
    $signedInForm=$form;
}
if(isset($username)){
    $signedInForm=$signedIn;

}  
$username="";
$email=$_POST['userEmail'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $msg_to_user3="Fill in both fields";
    }
    else{
    $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE userEmail='$email'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($results)==0)
       $msg_to_user3 ="No such User";
    else
    {
      while ($login_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
      {
       $password_db = $login_row['password'];
       if ($password!=$password_db){
         $msg_to_user3 ="Password doesn't match";
       }
         if ($password_db!=$password)

        $msg_to_user2="<a id='forgetpassword' href='convenientforgotpassword.php'>Forget Password</a>";

       else
       {

          $active = $login_row['active'];
          $userEmail = $login_row['userEmail'];
          if ($active==0)
             $msg_to_user3= "Activate account at ($userEmail) </p>";

        else
          { 
        //assign session
      $_SESSION['userName']=$username;

      }


      }
      }
    }
       }
}
```

Comment: Your login script is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Nowhere in there do you have a `session_start()`.

Comment: yes, I have a session_start();

Comment: I'm switching over to mysqli when I figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Because $username is always empty. You dont set it anywhere...

**EDIT**

Not always empty. But you overwrite it all the time.

Comment: How can I make the $signedIn show on the submit? Not on refreshing the page?

Comment: how do I set it if I don't have it set? I'm new so I have to see a code to understand.

Comment: I had to place the action of loading the $signedIn variable in the else with the set $_SESSION, that would change the div from $form to $signedIn when all the validation is correct during the submit. Then I also had to leave the isset $_SESSION to account for the refresh.

Comment: First of all, do you understand your code 100% - because it looks like the code is a mix from 1-2 other code snippets...
Second, you can set the $username variable when you fetch the data from mysql... Then you will not have a empty var to $_SESSION['userName']

Comment: while ($login_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
      {
       $password_db = $login_row['password'];

Here you can fetch users username and do like:
$username = $login_row['row_for_username'];